# PHPUnit with procedural code in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, phpunit

I am trying to use PHPUnit in netbeans. Code is procedural. PHPUnit is activated in neatbeans but I cannot create test file associated with any source file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually create a test file as netbeans is using phpunit-skelgen for test creation.

A detailed tutorial is found in waytoedu.com portal

http://answers.waytoedu.com/14/how-can-i-use-phpunit-in-netbeans-for-procedure-php-code